# Div margin to equal another div's height - JS

Tags: javascript, html, height

So my content div is basically hidden behind the header and footer, and has 100% height.
On some pages I want to have a JS script to tell the content div move below the header and I tried it like so but it's not working:

```
document.getElementById('content').style.marginTop = document.getElementById('header').height + 55;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you prepare a small fiddle which shows your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var height = document.getElementById('header').offsetHeight;
document.getElementById('content').style.marginTop = height + "px";
```